# Attach .txt, .pdf or zip file with skype bot using botframework rest-api

Tags: botframework, microsoft-skype-bot

I was trying to attach .txt and .pdf file to skype bot using [rest-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#attachment-operations) but got this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Unknown attachment type"
}
```

}

Meanwhile I found [Rest API attachment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389904/rest-api-attachment-error), can anyone confirm if pdf or text file attachment are restricted or not as there is no clear declaration in their api?
I tried with this format:

```
 {
    "type": "message",

   "recipient": {
        "id": "xxxxxxxJ0niMZOII93xxxxL1E"
    },
    "text": "Here's a picture of the duck I was telling you about.",
    "attachments": [
        {
          "contentType": "application/pdf",
          "contentUrl": "myfileurl",
          "name": "filename.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sending attachments such as PDFs is not supported in bots yet due to security concerns. Skype can only send media attachments such as audio and video.

You can refer it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4047#issuecomment-359482543)